# Django and Drupal

Tags: django, drupal

Since Django is a web development framework and Drupal is a CMS.

Is it possible to use them both together instead of a preferred database on Django like apache?

Maybe that question isn't clear enough.

Is it possible to use Django and Drupal simultaneously on the server side to provide a better web development solution?

Comment: Dear Webzide, the second part of your question doesn't make much sense. Can you please explain your project requirements? Apache itself is not a database, and "preferred database" is a subjective and dependent phrase.

Comment: Dennis D, could you please check that first sentence of your question? I guess you meant to say "... and Drupal is a CMS"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Drupal and Django side-by-side on the same server for different portions of your web site, but they will be entirely separate systems.  They cannot interact in any meaningful fashion (except possibly a Django app making web API calls to Drupal, if Drupal has a web API).

Django is a Python-based web development framework. Drupal is a CMS (and framework, through its module system) written in PHP.  They really can't use each other.

Comment: Although this answer is essentially correct, both systems can use mysql, and thus could theoretically be made to share data. Also, both have APIs that could be used to make them talk to each other. But unless you're trying to integrate some legacy code, I wouldn't go down this path. Pick your poison.

Comment: In addition, something like SQLAlchemy can be used from within Django alongside the built-in ORM to wrap the Drupal tables and access/query Drupal data.

Answer (score 4):

Communication between Drupal and any other system is possible and very common, especially using their Services module, and by calling other SOAP (and other) web services.

You can, if you want, to make both Django and Drupal work on the same server, and to call "localhost" for the services you are using, both ways. For Drupal, it is irrelevant where the actual server sits.

If you have a certain Django application you want to integrate with Drupal just write down what it is, and accordingly you will be able to get more help...

Regards,
Shushu

Comment: Not an ideal solution but a workable one. Can't help but think about some kind of internal API that wouldn't require access through the web-server...

Comment: You can try and share data by using the same database. It might work as well, and won't include the web server...

Comment: agreed though in practice I've run into trouble getting information to port from the Drupal structure to Django -- if I ever have a great enough need might write up an app that could do it but would take a fair amount of time to make it remotely generic enough to reuse -- btw: thanks for the tip on the services module - going to be implementing it on a site fairly soon to talk to an arduino project

Comment: Shushu is right. There is [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) on the Drupal side, and it can interact with an API exposed on Django by a REST API framework like [tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) on the Django side. In specific cases, you can actually avoid the Drupal thing at all using a [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to CRUD on your Django models through tastypie as you can do in Drupal + Services.