# Integrating python with drupal

Tags: python, drupal

I've just taken up a new contract position where the codebase is a Drupal system. I'm primarily a Python/Django backend developer, and have no experience with Druple. 
(Note, I have read this answer: [Django and Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710420/django-and-drupal))

I will need to integrate with the legacy system. The Drupal dev still works there, so can develop what is needed on the Drupal side, but it looks like I'll need to suggest the architecture. There are two points of interaction that are relevant.

1) Before data enters the database (from an external source, i.e. pre-runtime, no form data required), my scrips will do a lot of cleaning and formatting. I assume that this integration will be straightforward because there is currently no pre-database-entry code running. So I can just connect directly to the database instance are write in tables once it's been through my scripts.

2) I will be building search and analytics features for the website. These will need to run on form data, i.e., live.

What would be a good architecture for achieving the second integration? My thoughts are that I should develop a REST API endpoint. Drupal can send over a json or XML request, and I can return a json or XML response. Will this work on the Drupal side? Is there a better way to achieve an integration? I would like to try and keep things service orientated, or at least modular, so that the client doesn't end up with a fully integrated system in multiple languages that they can't maintain down the line.
Thanks!

Comment: Not enough details for a sound answer, sorry. But REST/json APIs are most deftly a sure way to decouple subsystems indeed.

Comment: Could you perhaps let me know what further details would help? Thanks.

Comment: Well, things like whether both systems work on the same database or are totally isolated, if the "search and analytics features for the website" are supposed to be part of the drupal site features (I assume yes but...) or just a BO part (and then what "requests" is drupal supposed to send),  etc etc.

Comment: They will share a database, yes, and search/analytics will be a site feature. However, a master/slave database setup could be an option (I have quite a bit of freedom). I know that elasticsearch, for example, usually maintains its own index in sync with a primary database. So for example, a user searches for x, and selects some filters, druple sends the search term to me with the filter tags, I do a lookup, return either the response, or a reference to the response and druple either renders the reponse to the user, or uses the reference to do its own quick lookup and then renders..

Comment: Drupal is modular enough to integrate advanced search and analytics features, have a look at [contributed modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/search-api/extension-modules) before throwing python in there ;)